# Check whether a date is before 1 january of a given year in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datetime

I need to verify if data entered into a form is before 1 January, 1940. I have the user's day, month and year values separately but I don't know how to use smarts to roll them all together and check whether or not they are before that specific date.

Comment: If it should be before 1 January 1940 you really just have to check that the year is before 1940 since 1 January is the first day of that year.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @ellak thanks - after thinking about it for a bit I believe you're right. It's been a long day :-/

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just create a Date object

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

than another Date with 1 january 1940 and you can just compare them : date1 < date2

Comment: Thanks. this is probably the best practice approach.

Comment: It's a general solution, but in this particular case I prefer ellak's approach :)